# php can't delete files on mounted samba share -permissions

Tags: apache, file-permissions, samba

My hair is going gray (or grayer that usual) trying to solve this riddle.

running: ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I want a PHP script (executed by apache) to delete a directory with all it's containing files in a cifs mounted directory. But I get "Permission denied".

The file is created by another samba client.

I have tried and tried , all different kinds of settings, but now I need some fresh eyes

Any comment appreciated 
B.R Lars

the file:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 countmaster countmaster 60897298 Sep 25 12:13 row_15.52.gz
```

the containing directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 countmaster countmaster 4096 Sep 25 13:34 SYNFR1.14247NEVB.1405281044/
```

the server smb.conf (i've used the default with slight modifications):

```
[global]
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        map to guest = Bad User
        guest account = countmaster
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        create mask = 0700
        printable = Yes
        print ok = Yes
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[share]
        comment = Countmaster File Server Share
        path = /nfs/countdata
        read only = No
        writeable =YES
        create mask = 0777
        force directory mode = 0755
        guest ok = Yes
```

The client /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.1.10/share /home/countserver/public_html/countdata  cifs auto,users,noperm,rw,guest,exec,actimeo=0 0 0
```

Comment: Does your Apache user (often www-data or apache) have permissions on the directory you're trying to modify? If not, it can't write/delete anything :)

Comment: yeah that's the realy good question. The file and directory permissions is shown in the post, here annybody has rw(x) permsissions, so www-data should have also - or?? . I'm getting lost in the relation between linux permissions and smb.conf settings.

Comment: I made it work. maybe not the most secure way, but it serve the purpose I want to achieve.  I added  force create mode = 0777
        force directory mode = 0777  to smb.conf

Comment: Although it works, using the phrase 'maybe not the most secure way' is usually an indication that you should perhaps keep looking at the problem